# Rails app: best way to only have admin user, no other user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to make a Rails app/site for my ownself where I can put up some info and some text. I was wondering how can I make an admin user (myself) in it without having a provision for any other user. I basically will never require more than one user and all other model data will belong to this one (admin) user.

The options I am thinking of:

1. Have a user model, with just one entry. Check if any user is logged in and show the admin utils.
2. Use a gem like can-can/devise? Is it an overkill?
3. Have a very obscure URL where I can carry out admin tasks (sounds lame but easiest!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"3." is not the safest option.
"1." it might take you some extra time (Michael Hartl's [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) might give you some ideas).

"2." is a bit of an overkill. You don't need CanCan, Devise alone will do, as long as you don't define routes for signing up and you don't put any link on your views for logging in.

Comment: so you suggest option 3 with devise? I don't intend to put any links. I'll have a route like /admin where i will put in my id/pwd and then I can see all admin tasks. that possible with devise?

Comment: yes, an obscure URL won't do alone, but you can have an URL for your sign in and use it. Devise will do everything else for you. Just remember to create your user (seeds.rb sounds like a good place), and start the controllers' methods you want to reserve for yourself: `return unless current_user`

Comment: will definitely do it if it served my purpose. know the rules here!!

Answer (score 3):

Would basic auth work for you?  Here's the rails cast on it...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the first option. This way you have a security layer without having to create a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

The first option seems nice... But I would go with the second since you will still need Authentication on your #1 and if you wish to add future features for other users you will be OK with CanCan + Devise.

Also they're pretty simple so I don't think it will give you that much trouble

Comment: No I don't want to add future features for any user. Then does 1 work? I suppose I don't need any kind of authentication then right?

Comment: Surely #1 would work. But as Miotsu said you will need to code a bit. You could remove CanCan and use only Devise so it handles login/session for you

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need some sort of authorization.

I recommend 3 options:

1. Build it your self
2. Use devise <- my goto
3. Use sorcery

Once your user model is created, then generate a migration called admin and set it as a boolean.

Then in your application.html.erb file, before the yeild call, create an if statement:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
<%= yield %>
<% else %>
You have no access
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role

I think this explains it step by step! Good luck